# Authorizing .NET Console App interactively with MFA to read sharepoint files

Tags: .net-core, sharepoint-online

I am throwing together a quick tool to do some automated processing of some files in Microsoft Sharepoint, using Multi Factor Authentication (MFA). I can open a connection with the PnP Powershell command:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -interactive -url "https://[tenantName].sharepoint.com"
```

Importantly with the above method, I do not need client-id, client-secret, tennant-id etc. to log in, because I don't have administrator access to the Sharepoint tenant, instead, my login simply has access to a subset of files I would like to read & process within a .net console App (as opposed to PowerShell above).

Is there a quick and easy way to simulate the above interactive behavior seen with the `Connect-PnPOnline` command, but from an asp.net console app (written in C#) - whereby the user can log themselves in, and subsequently the .net application can access the files on Sharepoint?

Answer (score 2):

To access SharePoint resources using Azure AD authentication, you typically need to register an application in Azure AD and acquire a client ID (also known as an application ID).

This client ID is crucial for identifying and authenticating your application to access SharePoint.

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    private const string graphScope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
    private const string sharePointScope = "https://[tenantName].sharepoint.com/.default";

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(null)
                    .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "[tenantId]")
                    .Build();

        var scopes = new[] { graphScope, sharePointScope };

        try
        {
            var result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                .ExecuteAsync();

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                    }));

            // Use graphClient to access SharePoint or Graph API resources
            // For example:
            var driveItems = await graphClient
                .Sites["{site-id}"]
                .Drive
                .Root
                .Children
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();

            foreach (var item in driveItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
        }
        catch (MsalException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring token: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sniffing out the tennantId using fiddler in the background and Connect-PnPOnline, and then using the PnP configuration:

```
"Credentials": {
  "DefaultConfiguration": "interactive",
  "Configurations": {
    "interactive": {
      "ClientId": "abcd-1234-",
      "TenantId": "abcd-1234-",
      "Interactive": {
        "RedirectUri": "http://localhost"
      }
    }
  }
},
"Sites": {
  "SiteToWorkWith": {
    "SiteUrl": "https://example.sharepoint.com/teams/myTeam",
    "AuthenticationProviderName": "interactive"
  }
}
```

then calling a startup method with

```
public static IHost HostBuilder()
{
    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddConsole();
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostingContext, services) =>
        {
            var config = hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("PnPCore");
            // Add the PnP Core SDK library services
            services.AddPnPCore();
            // Add the PnP Core SDK library services configuration from the appsettings.json file
            services.Configure<PnPCoreOptions>(config);
            // Add the PnP Core SDK Authentication Providers
            services.AddPnPCoreAuthentication();
            // Add the PnP Core SDK Authentication Providers configuration from the appsettings.json file
            services.Configure<PnPCoreAuthenticationOptions>(config);
```

and then in the main console app

```
using (var context = await pnpContextFactory.CreateAsync("SiteToWorkWith"))
```

Comment: There is a simple way to capture the tenantid if you know the tenantul.


https://login.microsoftonline.com/<teantURL>/.well-known/openid-configuration

This url will give you a response, in which token_endpoint will  have the tenant id. 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantID>/oauth2/token